Random Walks on the natural numbers with self loops
I am looking at a random walk that starts at 0 and at every step, either increases or decreases by 1, or doesn't move.
More specifically, $\mathbb{P} (X_{t+1} = X_t) = 1-p,\mathbb{P} (X_{t+1} = X_t +1) = p/2 + q/2 $ and $\mathbb{P} (X_{t+1} = X_t +1) = p/2 - q/2$.
Do we know something about the hitting time of a target $T>0$?
I know some results exist if $p=1$, namely something like $\min(T^2, \frac T q)$, do these results generalise for smaller $p$?
Many thanks!

What you call a random walk with self loops is called a lazy random walk in literature. Also, what do you call a target ? Is T a single element ? Is T a finite subset of the integers ? Is T any subset of the integers ? And could you please be more precise about the formula you are looking for and the one you think holds in the case $p=1$ ?
